# Does a compressed XML file affect performance and memory ? What are some tips for a better XML?

Tags: php, xml, compression

My question is if there is an easy way to compress an XML file. I read about EXI, gzip and similar, but I didn't understand how to do it, or if my question is possible.

What I am trying to achieve is to reduce the size of my XML file that I use with SimpleXML. Is that possible and if it is, will this have an impact on speed/performance/memory ?

Also, a large XML file is considered large based on the size or the number of elements?

Are there any tips that you should follow for a "better" XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think is just to remove as much unnecessary data as possible. i.e. don't make it formatted for human readability. That would include many unnecessary spaces/tabs/newlines. Use self closing tags whenever possible and just reduce the content down to the bare minimum that still meets XML specs. I'm sure there are compressors out there that do this. This kind of "compression" does not require decompression before parsing, but in turn may not save you much space.

Comment: Thank you for this. Self closing tags are for the empty elements right? Like `<desc></desc>` should be `<desc/>` ?

Comment: Yeah. In that example you went from 13 bytes to 7 bytes without causing any complications for the receiving XML parser to have to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it impacts the performance, because before any XML-parser can read the data, it must be uncompressed. How much memory it consumes depends on the compression and the XML-parser, but it will not use less memory (the reason is the same: It must get uncompressed anyway).

A "large XML" is considered large according both the file size and the number of elements, because the file size usually directly depends on the content (number of elements).

Comment: Yes, compressing and uncompressing always requires additional work to be done.

Answer (score 0):

There have been serious attempts to reduce XML overheads, see [Binary XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_XML) and [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipcomp/index.html)

There will be situations where reducing the amount of data to be sent over the wire is important, and it's worth paying some extra processing cost a each end.

There's some tension between using a self-describing but verbose format such as XML and then getting concerned about the resulting payload size. Adding in some form of binary compression is rather like paying for a rocket booster on a very luxurious but slow car, you're trying to get the best of both worlds.